# Can't install python modules on virtualenv using requirements.txt

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I am trying to install python modules from a `requirements.txt` file on a virtualenv. Pip runs, and installs them. But I can't import the modules installed, nor do they show up when I run `pip freeze`.

This is how I run pip

```
(test)elssar@elssar-laptop:~$ sudo pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt
```

I have even tried to run that command from the directory containing `requirements.txt` but nothing seems to work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try running it without `sudo`.

Comment: Doh! That worked, thanks. So if you'll just put that in an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running pip without `sudo`; it might set a different environment which overwrites the virtualenv settings.