# Pip not installing from requirements file to virtualenv - "Source in . has version ., which satisfies requirement . (from -r requirements.txt (line .)

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, virtualenv, pip

I'm experiencing issue similar to:

- [Can't install python modules on virtualenv using requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756965/cant-install-python-modules-on-virtualenv-using-requirements-txt)

and

- [Can't install python modules on virtualenv using requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756965/cant-install-python-modules-on-virtualenv-using-requirements-txt)

and

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1183

The difference is that i'm not using sudo.

- Ubuntu 12.04,
- pip 1.1
- python 2.7.3
- plain virtualenv (regardless if using virtualenvwrapper or not),

When i run pip install -r requirements.txt the output is suggesting downloading each dependency and after that i get such output of similar style for each dependency (I believe it has sth to do with last message):

```
Downloading/unpacking South==0.8.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
Running setup.py egg_info for package South
Running command python setup.py egg_info
running egg_info
writing pip-egg-info/South.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/South.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/South.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/South.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/South.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Source in /home/mstrecker/sample_env/build/South has version 0.8.4, which satisfies requirement South==0.8.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
```

After that pip freeze returns:

```
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.24
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Any idea any one? I don't want to type it manually :| If i do everything is fine and installed.

requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.4
PIL==1.1.7
Pillow==2.3.0
PyPDF2==1.19
South==0.8.4
Unidecode==0.04.9
argparse==1.2.1
chardet==2.2.1
coverage==3.5
distribute==0.6.24
django-common-helpers==0.6.0
django-cron==0.2.2
django-endless-pagination==2.0
django-extensions==1.3.3
django-haystack==2.0.0-beta
django-mockups==0.4.8
django-newsletter==0.3.0
django-nose==1.1
django-pylibmc==0.5.0
django-registration==0.8
django-timelog==0.4
html5lib==0.90
httplib2==0.7.6
nose==1.0.0
progressbar==2.3
psycopg2==2.5.2
pyPdf==1.13
pyelasticsearch==0.2
pylibmc==1.2.3
python-dateutil==2.0
pytz==2013.9
reportlab==2.5
requests==2.2.1
six==1.5.2
surlex==0.2.0
texttable==0.8.1
vobject==0.8.1c
wsgiref==0.1.2
xhtml2pdf==0.0.5
```

Comment: Try superuser.com since this is less related to programming itself but more about how to install a tool.

Comment: Having the same problem as well :S